# How to detect when an element scrolled at the top of a page in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am going to create a timeline for a website, something like [Google timeline](http://www.google.com/about/company/timeline/), I have some divs with the name of years with a class `separator` and when I scrolled up and reached a div at the top of page the year title at the left side should be changed to other year.

This is my HTML structure (just for example):

```
<div class="separator" data-year="2015">
  <!--Something Here-->
</div>

<div class="separator" data-year="2014">
  <!--Something Here-->
</div>

<div class="separator" data-year="2013">
  <!--Something Here-->
</div>


<div class="separator" data-year="2012">
  <!--Something Here-->
</div>
```

What should be my jquery code, and what functions should I use?

Comment: bind scroll even on window and check for the position of div and window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a very basic fiddle on what you can do:
http://jsfiddle.net/atq0sh6y/

The jQuery code:

```
$(document).scroll(function(){
    $('.separator').each(function(){
        var top = $(window).scrollTop();
        var off = $(this).offset();
        if(top>off.top) {
            $('.header').text($(this).data('year'));
        }
    });
});
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: What does `var off = $(this).offset();` return each time? one position? or it is smart and return the value of the needed div?

Comment: offset returns an object with 2 indexes: left, and top. That's why I wrote if(top>off.top)... off.left will also return a value with the x position (in pixels) of the given element. Also notice that offset will return the elements absolute position, even if it's not an absolute element in css!