# How does this fiddle each just return one value at each time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I see this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/atq0sh6y/4/) that was answered to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29728058/how-to-detect-when-an-element-scrolled-at-the-top-of-a-page-in-jquery), I know how does `each` work in jquery and it will do one thing on all element that we gave it. But in this fiddle it just return one thing according to scroll, I made something like that in my own computer and in my own project but it was returning all element with `separator` class

Comment: It doesn't return anything really... it just updates the text...

Comment: @odedta it seems to be returning `data-year` .. no?

Comment: @odedta I know, I just want to know why just one text, it should return 2015,2014,2013,2012,2011,2000,...

Comment: @gerdi I know, I just want to know why just one text, it should return 2015,2014,2013,2012,2011,2000,...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code actually doesn't only set one of the values. Depending on the scroll position it may set several values, but you only see the last value in the element.

The `if` statement skips the values that are below the window. At the start it sets only the `2015` value. When you are at the bottom it will set the text to `2015`, then `2014` then `2013` and then `2012`.

If you watch the console window, you will see all the texts that are set. When you are at the bottom each scroll movement sets all the text in turn.

---

Note that the code doesn't actually show the text from the element that is visible in the window, it shows the *last* element (in DOM order) that is in or above the window. If you used absolute or relative positioning to show the elements in a different order, the code would not work.

---

The code does less work if you call `scrollTop` once before the loop instead of inside the loop, and store the text in a variable and put it in the element after the loop instead of updating the element inside the loop:

```
$(document).scroll(function(){
    var text, top = $(window).scrollTop();
    $('.separator').each(function(){
        if (top > $(this).offset().top) {
           text = $(this).data('year');
        }
    });
    $('.header').text(text);
    console.log(text);
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/atq0sh6y/5/

Comment: What are other ways to get position of an element according to scroll? to do that

Comment: @LASH: That depends on what you want to do. You can for example compare the top and bottom position of the elements to the top and bottom position of the window (scroll position) to determine which elements are actually visible in the window.